# Mimic incremental calculation from excel in R

Tags: r, excel, dataframe, data-manipulation

I am attempting mimic a process that is currently done manually in Excel using R in order to help streamline the process so it doesn't need to be done manually. Here is an example of some sample data that I am working with (keep in mind this is a snippet of a much larger set of data).

```
qty_available<- c(13500, 8500, 4600)
supply_qty<- c(0, 1000, 0)
forecast<- c(1200, 400, 3000)
demand_q<- c( 100, 800, 6000)

df<- data.frame(qty_available, supply_qty, forecast, demand_q)
```

I am attempting to do the following manipulation (pseduo-code):

```
qty_available = previous(qty_available) + supply_qty - forecast - demand_q
```

I can ignore the first observation because it is irrelevant in the context of my task.

So in the second observation, we would have `13,500 + 1000 - 400 - 800` giving us `13,300`. The third observation would then be the `13,300 + 0 - 3000 - 6000` giving us `4300`.

If I were to open this dataset in Excel (read it in a CSV), the process is simple. I would use this formula in cell <kbd>A3</kbd> `= A2+B3-C3-D3`. Then just drag it down through the rest of the column.

How would I mimic this in R?

I have attempted doing so with the following command

```
df<- mutate(df, qty_available = lag(qty_available) + supply_qty - forecast - demand_q)
```

This command does not work since it is using the original 8500 rather than the newly calculated 13,300 in the lagged quantity available, and I am struggling to figure out another way to do it. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Desired output is as follows:

```
qty_available<- c(13500, 13300, 4300)

desired_output<- data.frame(qty_available, supply_qty, forecast, demand_q)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am thinking of using a simple for-loop:

```r
df1 <- data.frame(qty_available = c(13500, 8500, 4600),
                  supply_qty = c(0, 1000, 0),
                  forecast = c(1200, 400, 3000),
                  demand_q = c( 100, 800, 6000))

qty_available_new <- df1$qty_available[1]

for (i in 2:nrow(df1)) {
  qty_available_new[i] <- qty_available_new[i-1] + 
                                df1$supply_qty[i] - df1$forecast[i] - df1$demand_q[i]
}

df1$qty_available <- qty_available_new

df1
#>   qty_available supply_qty forecast demand_q
#> 1         13500          0     1200      100
#> 2         13300       1000      400      800
#> 3          4300          0     3000     6000
```

It is not as sophisticated as the other answer, but I wanted to show that loops would still be useful in R, even though there's this myth that we should steer clear of writing loops.

Answer (score 5):

Here `..1` is the previous value in the "accumulation" and `..3` is the next value of the second argument. The initial value for `..1` is the first element of the first argument.

```
library(tidyverse) # or dplyr and purrr

df %>% 
  mutate(newcol = accumulate2(qty_available, 
                              tail(supply_qty - forecast - demand_q, -1), 
                              ~ ..1 + ..3))
         

#   qty_available supply_qty forecast demand_q newcol
# 1         13500          0     1200      100  13500
# 2          8500       1000      400      800  13300
# 3          4600          0     3000     6000   4300
```

Another option (gives same output)

```
df %>% 
  mutate(newcol = accumulate(tail(supply_qty - forecast - demand_q, -1), `+`, 
                             .init = qty_available[1]))
```

And another without any `accumulate`

```
df %>% 
  mutate(newcol =  qty_available[1] + 
                    cumsum(replace(supply_qty - forecast - demand_q, 1, 0)))
```